# module not found python Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

1. application deployed without any issue (deployed via, VS code)
2. nothing in error logs
3. but while access app, getting module_not_found exception. It is for "durable function" module.
4. requirment.txt has required entries.

   azure-functions==1.12.0 azure-functions-durable==1.2.1    azure-common==1.1.28 azure-core==1.25.0 azure-datalake-store==0.0.52 azure-identity==1.7.1 azure-mgmt-consumption==9.0.0    azure-mgmt-core==1.3.0 azure-mgmt-resource==20.1.0    azure-storage-blob==12.13.1 azure-storage-file-datalake==12.8.0    adlfs==0.7.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. go to azure protal
2. go to "function app" landing page.
3. click on "ssh", it is one of the option on left menu.
4. once in ssh session type following command.

   pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r "/home/site/wwwroot/requirements.txt"